# My Python Custom transformer not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wrote this custom transformer in Python. Objective is to use it in Pipeline class for sequencing data prepocessing step. My datasets has 9 numerical and the 10th column is categorical.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def _init_(self, attribute_names):
       self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

After defining this class while I am trying to run this piece of code, I am getting error listed below

FYI.... datasets_num is a dataframe containing numerical column/attributes only.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
num_attributes = list(datasets_num)
cat_attributes = ["ocean_proximity"]

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attributes)),
        ('imputer', Imputer(strategy = "median")),
        ('std_scalar', StandardScaler()) 
        ])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
       ('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attributes)),
       ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer())
       ])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-f509d02ccc6e>", line 7, in <module>
     ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attributes)),

 TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def _init_(self, attribute_names):
```

you want double underscores:

```
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch... such a typical miss!!